# Itextsharp error "Unknown Filter: " when closing the stamper

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add a digital signature to a blank existing pdf, then create a new pdf with the digital signature with it.

Here's my code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfreader, fs, '\0');
stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("SIGNATURE");

PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
sap.Acro6Layers = true;

Font signatureFont = new Font();
signatureFont.Size = 10;

sap.Layer2Text = sb.ToString();
sap.Layer2Font = signatureFont; 

stamper.Close();    
pdfreader.Close();
fs.Close();
```

There's an exception when the stamper is being closed, and the exception says "Unknown Filter:"
can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell iTextSharp how to sign:

- You don't point it towards the private key to use.
- You don't tell it which kind of PDF signature to create.

In your case most likely the latter problem causes the error message, the kind of PDF signature fundamentally is given by a filter and a subfilter value.

In old iText(Sharp) versions these values were parameters of a `PdfSignatureAppearance.SetCrypto` method and a `PdfSignature` constructor call.

In current versions these values are set inside `MakeSignature` helper methods and `ExternalSignature` implementation constructors.

You might want to read [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures), a White Paper by Bruno Lowagie (iText Software) on the topic of signing PDFs using iText. iTextSharp/C# versions of the sample code can be found in the iTextSharp sourceforge repository.